# Is JAVA 1.7 stable or still beta version?

Tags: java

I want to switch to Java 1.6 from 1.5 but I think it's better to go with 1.7 instead of 1.6.
Is 1.7 stable or still in beta?

Comment: "Early Access" is Oracle speech for Alpha/Beta versions

Comment: I'd suggest running your tests on 1.7 as well as 1.6. You wouldn't want 1.7 to come out and hit a bug either in the Java library or your code. If you catch a bug in 1.7, it could get fixed before release. More difficult to do that after FCS, although it's already a bit late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the moment we are working with 1.6 and still no plans to migrate. I recommend not going to last version. We think it isn't stable yet.

Answer (score 8):

> **Is JAVA 1.7 stable or still beta version?**

Technically it is still in beta.

> **So is 1.7 is stable?**

This is the [current time plan](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/):

> - 2010/12/23  Feature Complete (M11)
> - 2011/02/17  Developer Preview (M12)
> - 2011/04/12  Rampdown start: P1-P3 bugs only
> - 2011/04/28  API/interface changes: Showstoppers only
> - 2011/05/11  All targeted bugs addressed
> - 2011/05/18  Bug fixes: Showstoppers only
> - 2011/06/02  Last scheduled build (M13)
>
> Final test cycle starts
>
> - 2011/07/28  General Availability

Decide for yourself when you consider it to be stable :-)

Since the API/interface changes was fixed (except for "showstoppers") yesterday I would consider it to be fairly stable. (I wouldn't use it for nuclear power plants or space rockets just yet though.)

Comment: :-) You are not supposed to use Java for nuclear power plants; see http://www.java.com/en/download/license.jsp (section 3.).

Comment: @Stephen C, Hahaha great comment

Comment: Apparently space rockets are fine, though

Answer (score 2):

Java 1.7 was formally released on 28th July 2011.

http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/press/444374

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 is still beta. You should use 6 unless you want to experiment or test the new features. If you're concerned about performance, the vast majority of improvements have been back ported into the later Java 6 updates. It's also very stable.

Comment: +1: To put it another way, They are not developing a different JVM for Java 6 and 7, the JVM is the same except Java 7 tends to have the latest changes sooner (i.e. Java 6 has a slightly old version which has been tested for longer, it about 3-9 months older depending on the release)